# Unable to pass Timestamp variable from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to pass a timestamp variable from jsp to servlet, but in the jsp file itself when I put it inside value of input tag " . The time part gets trimmed and only Date is visbible. Please find attached image and code for better understanding. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<%
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
  Date parsedDate = df.parse((request.getParameter("dateOut")));
  java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
  AdminService adminservice = new AdminService();
  
  out.println(timestamp);
  //BookLoans booksl =adminservice.getallBookloansDateout(t);

%>

<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
    aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">DUE DATE</h4>
</div>
      
<form action="overrideDuedate" method="post">
  <div class="modal-body">
    ENTER NUMBER OF DAYS YOU WANT TO EXTEND BOOK BY
    <input type="text" name="extendDays"> 
    <input type="text" name="dateOut" value=<%=timestamp%>>
    
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">OVERRIDE DATE</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using java.sql.TimeStamp?

Comment: I wanted it in that format. @11thdimension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with value=`'<%=timestamp%>'`

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp won't have a format, it's an object based on the point in time value (milliseonds) if you need formatted date then convert it to String using the `SimpleDateFormat`.

That means there was no need to parse the date in the first place. Following should work.

```
value=<%=request.getParameter("dateOut")%>
```

Parsing of this value can be done in your Servlet @ `/overrideDuedate`